# why I have target Error when i did HTMX inline editing?

Tags: python, django, htmx

I'm doing a Django project and want to use HTMX to achieve inline edit, I can click the title to change the text, but once I click the save button, it shows targetError. I just checked that I used the correct reference name. I couldn't figure out where is my mistake.

view.py

```
def editProject(request,pk):
    project=Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(project.name)
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.method)
        project.name=request.POST.get('name','')
        print(f'project name: {project.name}')
        project.save()
        return render(request,'tool/{project.id}',{'project':project})
    return render(request,'tool/partials/editProject.html',{'project':project})
```

ProjectDetail.html

```
      <h1 id="projectName"
      hx-get="{% url 'tool:editProject' pk=project.pk%}"
          hx-target="this"
          hx-swap="outerHTML">
      {{project.name}}</h1>
```

editProject.html

```
<form
    hx-post="{% url 'tool:editProject' pk=project.pk%}"
    hx-target="closest h1"  <!-- I also tried use #projectName, still not working -->
    hx-swap="outerHTML"
    hx-headers="{ 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' }"
    class="flex"
    >
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{project.name}}"  autofocus>
    <button class="text-sky-600 hover:text-sky-900"> Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your content is replaced with edit form, your target does not exist anymore, so instead you should wrap you content around `div` tag and use it for targeting with the innerHTML in both templates, smth like:

```
hx-target="closest div"
hx-swap="innerHTML" # not really required, since it's the default behaviour
```

Also your POST render response should include proper template. Seems like you're missing the template name there.

Comment: Thank you for your help,  I have some misunderstanding about HTMX, your answer is really helpful.